# Options for list within a fixed width, HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Do you know of a good solution for dealing with text entries of variable lengths lists with a fixed width?

I have an unordered list with a set number of items.  Each item contains a title.  The title can be variable length, not only in number of characters, but also number of characterset (korean, japanese, roman, etc.).

One option seems to be cutting the text length down with PHP and adding "..." at the end, but since character widths can be variable, the exact cutoff can also be variable. Another would be to make items fixed with and hide overflow, but this seems inelegant (because characters might get cutoff right in their centers...).

Do you know of a good tutorial or solution for something like this?

Comment: Can't you just let the text wrap? If the text doesn't contain any/enough spaces you could add additional spaces with PHP in "long words".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS: `text-overflow: ellipsis`. Doesn't work in all browsers though. More information: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html.

Comment: Great solution.  I'd never heard of the ellipsis thing before.